# Call a Jquery function inside the same (.js) file and another PHP file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, function, methods

I have a js file with Jquery function now i have to call that function on document ready and inside another PHP file i tried below codes it worked for PHP file but for the JS file it is saying `$.test is not a function`

**jq.js file** for this error message was `$.test is not a function`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.test();

    $.test =    function(){
        alert('HELLO WORLD');
    }
});
```

**add.php file** For this worked.

```
.....SOME PHP CODES HERE ....
<td class="del"><span class="fa fa-times"></span></td>

<script>
    $('.delI').unbind().click(function(){       
        $.test();       
    });
</script>
```

I have to call this test() function inside the same JS file and in another PHP file too please give me a solution..  thanks.

Comment: You have to call it **after** you define it, not before

Comment: @A.Wolff it worked Thanks. do you think this method secure? or there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you call `$.test` before you defined it. Call it after the definition:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.test =    function(){
        alert('HELLO WORLD');
    }

    $.test();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.test =    function(){
        alert('HELLO WORLD');
    }
})();
```

Call the function after you define it, not before.

Or:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            $.test =    function(){
                alert('HELLO WORLD');
            }
      $.test();
        });
```